# NSTableCellView customization in MAC OS

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I want to subclass `NSTableCellView` with XIB. I am new on MAC OS programming.

This is what I have done on :

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if (tableView == self.tableVSurah) {
        CustomCell *cell;
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 302, 52)];

        cell.txtTName.stringValue = [[arrData objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"tname"];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

where `CustomCell` is `NSTableCellView`.

Though I am good in iOS where I was using following code to get `.xib` of that particular `UITableViewCell`. The following code is written in UITableView subclass.

```
+ (CustomCell *)cellFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName {

     NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];
     NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
     CustomCell *xibBasedCell = nil;
     NSObject* nibItem = nil;

     while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
           if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                 xibBasedCell = (CustomCell *)nibItem;
                 break; 
           }
     }

     return xibBasedCell;
}
```

For Mac we do not have `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];` method.

How do I load that particular `xib` in my `NSTableView` ?

Answer (score 0):

In mac we have this API:-

```
    - (BOOL)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName owner:(id)owner 
topLevelObjects:(NSArray **)topLevelObjects
```

Comment: Yes, but it will not give me that xib's object. It will just return whether its already loaded or not.